# Question on pure rolling

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Let us take a sphere of radius $R$. Let a $F$ force act on its center of mass to make it roll on a rough surface. We need to find the acceleration of the sphere.

Conventionally, I figured out the instantaneous axis of rotation, of the sphere which is the bottommost point or point of contact of the sphere with the surface. $I_{CR}=I_{COM}+mR^2$, or $I_{CR}=\frac{7}{5}mr^2$

Hence $$FR=\frac{7}{5}mR^2\alpha$$
$\alpha R=a_{COM}$
Hence: $$a_{COM}=\frac{5}{7m}F$$

Although I figured out that if assume that the sphere is rolling about the center of mass, and write a torque equation for friction and solving we get the same result:
$$F-f=ma$$
$$fR=\frac{2}{5}mR^2\alpha$$
$$a_{COM}=\frac{5}{7m}F$$

However, we had been taught to always analyze motion about the instantaneous axis only. So why are we getting the same result? Am I doing something wrong here? Please resolve my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually solve any problem in any reference frame using any axis you want, it is actually very instructive to do so like you did.

The only thing you need to check is if the equations you use apply in that particular context that you choose (i. e. what are the conditions or hypotheses that were used when deducing that equation).

Sometimes the math is simpler in a particular reference frame or sing a particular axis, but this of course depends on the particularity of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.